# How to make page swipe app in swift?

Tags: swift, swipe, pagingmenucontroller

A few days ago, I made Android app. And now I should make same app in IOS. So, I'm studying swift. To make same app with Android, I'm looking for
library like 'ViewPager' in Android. I searched that and found some libraries, but they were custom libraries. I just want to use library formed like 'ViewPager'. Many people said, what you want is 'PagingMenuController'. But I couldn't find formed library about that.

To change view with tab or swipe, should I use 'PageMenuController'?

If it is true, who can tell me how to use it? It doesn't matter that link or youtube, please tell me about it. I'm new in swift, so if it contains image or media it is more good for me.

Comment: [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) is what you need, or you can use a UIScrollView and enable paging. Google for tutorials

Comment: @Scriptable If I use PageViewController, Can I change view with tap icon? I know that I can change view with swipe when I use 'PageViewController'. But Can I use tab click too? I want to use PageViewController and TabViewController at once.

Comment: yes you can use both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are trying to make Intro pages like UI

You can use `UIPageViewController`

Following are the links you can consider

1. https://medium.com/how-to-swift/how-to-create-a-uipageviewcontroller-a948047fb6af
2. https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

If you prefer the Third-Party Support, you can use following links:

1. https://github.com/hyperoslo/Pages
2. https://github.com/tzef/BmoViewPager
3. https://github.com/emalyak/EMPageViewController
4. https://github.com/uias/Pageboy
5. https://github.com/theothertomelliott/TEQuickPageViewController
6. https://github.com/uias/Tabman
7. https://github.com/naoto0822/SwipePager

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to use PageViewController and TabViewController at once. like if I want to go to second view, swipe 1 time or tab second icon.

Comment: You are ok with using third party libraries.? So i can suggest you one

Answer (score 0):

> UICollectionView
>
> UICollectionViewLayout

From Apple Docs:

> The layout object to use. Use this control to select between the UICollectionViewFlowLayout object and a custom layout object that you
> define.
>
> When the flow layout is selected, you can also configure the scrolling
> direction for the collection view’s content and whether the flow
> layout has header and footer views. Enabling header and footer views
> adds reusable views to your storyboard that you can configure with
> your header and footer content. You can also create those views
> programmatically.
>
> When a custom layout is selected, you must specify the
> UICollectionViewLayout subclass to use.

Docs: Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about CocoaPods ?
 there are some useful libraries that you can use to animate your app (like [Hero](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) ) ; for page Swiping there is [**Pageboy** : a simple, highly informative page view controller.](https://github.com/uias/Pageboy) .

**If you do not know what  is cocoa pods or how to install it** , check out this video ([Cocoa Pods Tutorial - How to install and setup Cocoa Pods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNKVVBN2JN0))